# Wholesale and retail functions not working for adding to cart

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, e-commerce

I am trying to build the price as wholesale and retail. So if the user clicks on wholesale, it should show an input with quantity amount inside it and if the user click on add to cart, it should take the wholesale price, and when click on "Buy wholesale" then it should let the user input the number of items they want to buy and should be added to the cart as retail price. Right now, when I click on "buy wholesale", and click on add to cart, it takes the quantity and add the price as wholesale, but when I click on retail, it also takes the wholesale price and quantity. Doesn't add as retail.

```
                <label class="checkbox-inline">
  <input type="checkbox" name= "checkbox" id="chk" onclick="ShowHideDiv(this)" value="">&nbsp;Buy 
Wholesale
</label>&nbsp;
<label class="checkbox-inline">
  <input type="checkbox" name = "checkbox" id="chk" onclick="ShowHideDiv1(this)" value="">&nbsp;Buy 
Retail
</label>
</div>

<div id="dvPass" style="display: none">
<input name="qty" size="10" type="number" id="txtNumber" value="<?php echo 
$single['pro_quantity_stock']?>" disabled />
</div>

<div id="dvPass1" style="display: none">
<input name="qty" size="10" type="number" id="txtNumber1" />
</div>

<a href="#" class="btn btn-info btn-normal" onclick="add_cart_func(<?= $single['id']?>, 
                                                                                        '<?= 
$single["pro_title"]?>', 
                                                                                        '<?= $price? 
>')">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span> ADD TO CART
                    </a>
```

Comment: `$price = $this->session->cert=='ok' ? $single["pro_wholesale"] : 
$single["pro_retail"];` , this statement is inside a if statement, So, it will naver get  `pro_retail` value.

Comment: Post other js functions as well.

Comment: I have added the js function for add_to_cart

Answer (score 0):

```
let qty = $("input[name='qty']").val();
```

Here is the problem. Even one of them is hidden, it still in the DOM. Try something like following.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var type = "txtNumber";
function ShowHideDiv(chk) {
    var dvPass = document.getElementById("dvPass");
    dvPass.style.display = chk.checked ? "block" : "none";
    type = "txtNumber";
}

    function ShowHideDiv1(chk) {
    var dvPass1 = document.getElementById("dvPass1");
    dvPass1.style.display = chk.checked ? "block" : "none";
    type = "txtNumber1";
}
</script>
```

and

```
let qty = $("#"+type).val();
```

Comment: I have tried this, where should I add the last line- let qty = $("#"+type).val();

Comment: Replace with `let qty = $("input[name='qty']").val();`